# How to correctly add a row to a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this `DataGrid`:

[image]

Code:

```
        <DataGrid Name="DatabaseView1" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This datagrid contains several entries one after the other. I collect the entries in a list:

```
        public static List<Entry> Entries = new List<Entry>();
        public class Entry
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
```

I add a new entry like this:

```
Entries.Add(new Entry {FirstName = "Christiano", LastName = "Ronaldo", Age = "35"});
```

I add the entries like this to the `DataGrid`:

```
DatabaseView1.ItemsSource = Entries;
```

This is my result:

[image]

You see that two entries are created. Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double columns are being generated because you have not told `DataGrid` to stop auto generating columns for assigned `ItemSource`. So, to disable `AutoGenerateColumns` Just set the `AutoGenerateColumns = False` in xaml DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid Name="DatabaseView1" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns = "False">
```